# Can't boot ISO from USB UNetbootin

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu, unetbootin

I was trying to install Linux Mint and a few other OS's through UNetbootin. (Xubuntu 12.04) The ISO's burned alright, but when I tried to boot them up, I got the message: "Non-system boot disk. Press any key to reboot."  I've done this several times, and I can't figure this out, so please help if you can.

Comment: This is askubuntu , for Ubuntu related issues. Not for MINT.

Comment: @Sushantp606 They also tried Xubuntu, so I think this question is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to boot a new install from usb and it turned out I was using a 64-bit 12.04 instead of the correct-for-this-netbook 32-bit.